# How do I change State to a Country in Tableau?

Tags: maps, state, country, tableau-api

Tableau seems to think that Scotland is a State rather than a country. I'm trying to highlight the country Scotland as well as other countries but I can't. It does recognize Scotland at a State/Province level. Is there any way I can change the settings so I can show it as a country?

Thank you,

Michael

Answer (score 1):

It's only possible to set an entire field Geographic Role. Meaning, if in your data the "Scotland" entry is in a field (let's call it "Location") where you have typically states or provinces, you won't be able to tell Tableau that "Scotland" is a Country and other entries are States/Provinces.
Only thing you can do is tell Tableau that "Location" hold Country information. For that, right click on the field, go for Geographic Role, and select Country/Region.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this problem, because tableau not recognizing Uk countries 
(England, Scotland, Wales, NORTHERN IRELAND).

But I have done this one by small tricky process here are the details what I have done.

1. Create a filled map using the Country field and the desired measure.
2. Right-click on the country field and duplicate the field. The new field is called "Country (Copy)" in the attached workbook.
3. Right click on Country (Copy), go to Geographic Role and select "State/Province". We now have 2 copies of the country field, however, Tableau is reading one as country data and one as a province data.
4. Step one will have brought Longitude to Columns and Latitude to Rows, for the next step drag a second copy of latitude to rows, right-click on it and select "Dual Axis". The map should not have changed since step 3.
5. Now click on the 2nd instance of Latitude in the Marks card and remove Country.
6. Drag Country (Copy) to detail on the Marks card.
7. There will be an "Unknown" box in the bottom right corner of the map, click on this, change the Country/Region to United Kingdom and then click OK. All countries should be plotted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is you can change the default type of dimension and set is as country as whole. and then if the problem still persist you can edit the location after the map is plotted. HTH